# Bootstrap modal. screen goes grey when close the modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Hey im trying to use modal : 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

But when i press the delete button the screen goes grey, and i cant click anything. any suggestions?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="nextsidoradmin" 
 ng-click="SendSidor(worker.id)">CreateShift</button>
 <div class="modal fade" id="mymodal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <h3><span style="color:red;">{{worker.name}</span>:Deleteworker</h3>
<div class="modal-body">
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="RemoveWorker(worker.id)" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ui-sref="workers" >Cancel</button>
</div></div></div></div></div>

$scope.RemoveWorker=function(workerid){
    $http.delete("/ShiftWeb/rest/admin/removeworker?id="+workerid)
            .then(function(response){$scope.removeworker=response.data;
            $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
            $('#mymodal').modal('hide');
            console.log(response.data);
            }, function(error) {
                alert(error.data);
            }
            );
};
```

https://prnt.sc/k67ypc

https://prnt.sc/k67yrw

and i think its releated to state.reload. anyone knows?
any suggestions?

Comment: It works fine if you paste your code into the Tryit editor in the w3schools link. Therefore, it must be something in `RemoveWorker(worker.id)` - try removing that.

Comment: Well i need it xD its the function... and i think its releated to state.reload. anyone knows?

Comment: Thanks for showing the code for RemoveWorker. I don't think that is causing the problem.

Comment: Why are you not using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ? its the same thing but in angular way, so you wont get any bugs in future. Using jquery bootstrap is a big NO NO.  In case, u want to fix this one, please share a plunkr so that we can take a look at it